# ECS is there a way to avoid downtime when I change instance type on Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have created a cluster to run our test environment on Aws ECS everything seems to work fine including zero downtime deploy, But I realised that when I change instance types on Cloudformation for this cluster it brings all the instances down and my ELB starts to fail because there's no instances running to serve this requests.

The cluster is running using spot instances so my question is there by any chance a way to update instance types for spot instances without having the whole cluster down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an AutoScaling group? This would allow you to change the launch template or config to have the new instances type. Then you would set the ASG desired and minimum counts to a higher number. Let the new instance type spin up, go into service in the target group. Then just delete the old instance and set your Auto scaling metrics back to normal.

Without an ASG, you could launch a new instance manually, place that instance in the ECS target group. Confirm that it joins the cluster and is running your service and task. Then delete the old instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for this cluster i don't because I use spot instances, so I guess is everything based on spot-fleet requests, please correct if I'm wrong but I cannot change the minimum count for spot instances correct it has to be 0 always?

Comment: No, you can use spot instances in a scaling group. You can also use spot diversity to specify other instances types. Often times when making a spot request, if there isnt enough capacity, launching an instance can fail. Using 4 or 5 different similar instance types can overcome the lack of availability. For example, I have used spot diversity using m4.large, m5.large, c4.large, c5.large, and t3.large instance types. Assuring that I always got a replacement instance

Comment: Sorry took me a bit longer to get back to you, you were absolutely right, when i created these clusters I did it using the Wizard so in the the whole cluster was relying on cloudformation. with your advice i created empty clusters and a auto scaling group as you suggested and providing the right user data i can have more flexibility and upgrade instances without bring everything down.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to break this activity in smaller chunks and do it one by one. You can write small cloudformation template as well because by default if you update the instance type then your instances will be restarted and to avoid zero downtime, you might have to do it one at a time.

However, there are two other ways that I can think of here but both will cost you money.

1. ASG: Create a new autoscaling group or use the existing one and change the launch configuration.
2. Blue/Green Deployment: Create the exact set of resources but this time with updated instance type and use Route53's weighted routing policy to control the traffic.

It solely depends upon the requirement, if you can pour money then go with above two approaches otherwise stick with the small deployments.